# Problema a la hora de guardar un gráfico realizado con una función PYTHON

Tags: python, seaborn

Os traigo un problema con el que llevo lidiando desde hace unos días. He realizado una función que introducido un dataframe, te realiza un gráfico con seaborn que muestra los missing values que ahy en cada columna, por así decirlo. El gráfico lo realiza correctamente y el problema no está aquí.

La cosa es que cuando ejecuta la línea en la que se debería de guardar el gráfico en una carpeta que especifico mediante el comando plt.savefig no me lo guarda porque es como que no reconoce el nombre, mostrándome el siguiente error:

> ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) -> dtype('<U21')

Disculpen mi ignorancia y sobretodo lo mal que me explico, pero empezamos este año con Python y la terminología me falla bastante (si sabéis de algún pdf en el que pueda encontrar información sobre terminología de programación y queréis adjuntarlo también lo agradecería ;)). El código del que hablo es el siguiente y me gustaría que se guardara con el nombre del dataframe que se especifica en la función.

```
def viz_missing_values(df):
plt.figure(figsize = (10,6))
sns.displot(
    data = df.isna().melt(value_name="missing"),
    y = "variable",
    hue = "missing",
    multiple = "fill",
    aspect = 1.25
)
plt.savefig("graficos/" + df + ".png", dpi=100)
```

Si en el parámetro de la función pongo df_itinearios, me gustaría que se guardara como df_itinearios.png. He intentado hacerlo metiéndolo en un str() en el savefig pero no me lo hace ya que me guarda como str todo el contenido del dataframe y me devuelve error. A ver si alguno podéis echarme una ayudita, y muchas gracias de antemano. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sería tan fácil como añadir la siguiente línea de código en la función:

`name = [x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df][0]`

En el savefig habría que reemplazar name por df, dejando el código final de la siguiente manera:

```
def viz_missing_values(df):
plt.figure(figsize = (10,6))
sns.displot(
    data = df.isna().melt(value_name="missing"),
    y = "variable",
    hue = "missing",
    multiple = "fill",
    aspect = 1.25
)
name = [x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df][0]
plt.savefig("graficos/" + name + ".png", dpi=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

buscando un poco encontré que podrías realizar esto:

```
df_itinearios.name = 'df_itinearios'
print(df_itinearios.name)
```

Entonces al momento de llamar a tu funcion

```
def viz_missing_values(df):
plt.figure(figsize = (10,6))
sns.displot(
    data = df.isna().melt(value_name="missing"),
    y = "variable",
    hue = "missing",
    multiple = "fill",
    aspect = 1.25
)
plt.savefig("graficos/" + df + ".png", dpi=100)
```

Podrias llamarla de la siguiente forma:

```
viz_missing_values(df_itinearios.name)
```

Saludos...

Comment: Buenos días @Poenix111. Antes de nada muchas gracias por tu ayuda. El problema es que mediante ese método no es posible automatizar la función ya que tendría que asignar un nombre a cada uno de los dataframes. A continuación, como respuesta a mi pregunta pondré la solución que me ha funcionado y automatiza toda la función para personas que puedan tener mi misma duda.

Comment: Claro, es una forma de hacerlo, quizá esta solución podría funcionar si al momento de cargar el dataset le otorgamos el nombre a partir del nombre del archivo por ejemplo. Saludos...